# Черные, гладко причесанные волосы - почему здесь определения однородные?

Tags: однородные-неоднородные-определения

На сайте "Лицей":

1. Черные причесанные волосы.
2. Чёрные, гладко причёсанные волосы.

В первом предложении черные и причесанные - неоднородные определения.

Добавляем "гладко". Почему определения становятся однородными?

Comment: Можно и в первом предложении считать однородными.

Answer (score 2):

Как я понимаю, дело в том, что правило требует поставить запятую, если у вас на втором месте причастный оборот. А называть эти определения можете как хотите, точнее говоря, в данном случае их называют однородными, потому что ставится запятая, а не наоборот.